# Does amp-access work with amp-story? Will amp-subscription overtake amp-access for amp-story?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story, amp-access

Does amp-story work with amp-access (or amp-subscription)?

**here is sample code for amp-access**

```
<script id="amp-access" type="application/json">
  {
      "authorization": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-access/authorization?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL&ref=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&_=RANDOM",
      "pingback": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-access/authorization?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL&ref=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&_=RANDOM",
      "login": {
        "sign-in": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-access/login?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL",
        "sign-out": "https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-access/logout"
      },
      "authorizationFallbackResponse": {
          "error": true,
          "access": false,
          "subscriber": false
      }
  }
</script>
```

**the required setup**

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-access" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-access-0.1.js"></script>
```

**references**

- [the amp-access component](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-access/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paywall support for amp-story is currently under development.  You can track its progress in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/12180).